# The use of "may only" and "may not" in standardized or mathematical language

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I am utterly confused by the term "may only" and "may not" when it comes to standards and mathematics.

For example:

> The resulting set may only have one element.

Does this mean:

1. It is only possible for the resulting set to have one element.

or

2. It is possible for the resulting set to have only one element.

Another example:

> The resulting set may not contain any element.

Does this mean:

1. It is only possible for the resulting set to contain no element (i.e. an empty set).

or

2. It is possible for the resulting set to contain no element.

Comment: In a mathematical context I would choose 2: I would use "may" to denote possibility.  Perhaps in general speech, "may" has other meanings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. The pragmatics of these usages are maths-specific, and would not apply in general English usage.

Comment: Mathematical writing varies in quality, just like every other type of writing. However, with *may*, you can probably get the intended sense by substituting *is allowed to*. Probably.

Comment: "may" is ambiguous between a "permissible" and a "possible" reading in both your examples.  "only" in the first example modifies "one" (even though it is not next to "one").  It is a complicated question. (I started to work out an answer, but got bogged down.)

Answer (score 2):

It could mean either one; the correct meaning has to be determined from context.

The meaning of "the resulting set may only have one element" may be either

- that it is **possible** for the resulting set to have only one element, or
- that it is **mandatory** for the resulting set to have only one element.

Since the sentence is talking about "the resulting set," it is reasonable to guess that it's expressing a possibility, not a mandate. But more context is needed in order to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

No. In these usages, the *may* has the deontic meaning of "permission", not the epistemic meaning of "possibility".

> The resulting set may only have one element.

The resulting set is permitted to have at most one element.

> The resulting set may not contain any element.

The resulting set must be empty.

In normal language, these would be ambiguous, and the epistemic meaning possible; but in the semi-formal language of mathematics, that meaning would be expressed differrently.

Comment: This answer on Math.SE seems to say the opposite: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1596062/13524 It says that in mathematics, the word "may" usually refers to possibility, not permission.

Comment: IMHO, this question has nothing to do with possibility vs permission, but whether ‘not’ negates ‘may’ or the main verb.

Comment: Given that the first example doesn't contain _not_, that seems hard to maintain.

Comment: Given that English is different in this regard than many other languages where this ambiguity would never arise, such as German, it seems obvious.

Comment: Just a quick illustration: Let's write req(S) (require) and allow(S) and note that req(S) is formally equivalent to not(allow(not S)) [whether deontic or epistemic]. "A can be empty" means allow(A empty), "A cannot be empty" means not(allow(A empty)) ['not' applied outside]. However, "A must be empty" means req(A empty), i.e. not(allow(not(A emty))), whereas "A must not be empty" means req(not(A empty)), i.e. not(allow(A empty)) ['not' applied inside]. It is clear that "A may be empty" means allow(A empty), but "A may not be empty" may be either allow(not(A empty)) or not(allow(A empty)).